# Insert data in HTML from php

Tags: php

I trying to put user data from `PHP` in `HTML` form, like name, email, address, etc. But i don't know what i have to do to work it.

Already tried:

```
<?php

  session_start();
  $test='some name';
  $_SESSION['name']='some name';

?>

<a href="<?php $_SESSION['name']; ?>"></a>

<!-- AND -->

<a href="<?php $test; ?>"></a>
```

and nothing happened.

**SOLVED CODE**:

```
<?php

  session_start();
  $test='some name';

?>

<a><?= $test ?></a>
```

Comment: You need to output it. Try `echo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP manual has a page introducing the [PHP tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php):

> When PHP parses a file, it looks for opening and closing tags, which are  which tell PHP to start and stop interpreting the code between them.

Note that "interpreting the code" is *not* the same as displaying the *result* of that code. For instance, you could write `<?php $test = 'hello'; ?>` to assign a new value to a variable, and it won't cause anything to be output.

To output a string, you can use the [`echo`](https://php.net/echo) and [`print`](https://php.net/print) keywords. Note that these are not functions, so do not have parentheses around their arguments; as noted in the manual, including redundant parentheses will *sometimes* work, but can be misleading. So the following output the variable `$test` into the page:

```
<?php echo $test; ?>
<?php print $test; ?>
```

As the PHP tags page I linked to earlier says:

> PHP includes a short echo tag `<?=` which is a short-hand to the more verbose `<?php echo`.

So you can also use:

```
<?= $test ?>
```

However, you also have a *second* problem, which is nothing to do with PHP, and will happen if you hard-code a URL into your HTML like this:

```
<a href="https://example.com"></a>
```

Nothing will appear in the browser! Why? Because you've defined the *destination* of a link, but haven't defined any *text or content* to click on; you need it to look like this:

```
<a href="https://example.com">Click me if you dare!</a>
```

So put that together, you might write this in PHP:

```
<a href="<?= $linkUrl ?>"><?= $linkDescription ?></a>
```

Comment: So thanks for explication, now i know what error i did and how solve it <3

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
<a href="<?php $test; ?>"></a>
```

to this

```
<a href="<?php echo($test); ?>"></a>
```

or to this if you want to see the data on the html page

```
<a href="<?php $test; ?>"><?php $test; ?></a>
<a href="<?php echo($test); ?>"><?php echo($test); ?></a>
```

Do note that there are better ways to display such data. Check this out:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_echo_print.asp

Comment: Exco does not need the brackets. a simple `echo $var;` is fine

Comment: Nothing happened yet, only appear when i put something inside like ```<a href="<?php echo($test); ?>"> aaa </a>```i did something wrong?

Comment: Not only does `echo` not _need_ parentheses, using them can cause confusion and bugs, so is generally a bad habit; see "Note: Using with parentheses" on https://php.net/echo The same is true for other "language constructs", like `print`,  `include`, `require`, etc

Comment: Thanks for the parentheses info